# Stopping iOS backspace deleting whole words or lines?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

## Background

Even though I have owned every iPhone from the 3G onwards I have NEVER mastered the backspace key. If you hold it to delete a few words it almost ALWAYS catches me out and starts deleting whole words and then whole lines (if you keep it pressed).
I just want it to continue deleting one letter at a time until I remove my finger. If I want to delete huge blocks I would highlight them. :)

## Question

Is there ANY way to prevent this? 
My iPhone 5 is Jailbroken so I'm sure there must be a way but no matter how much searching I do I can't for the life of me find it.

Thanks

Comment: I've started to remove symbol by symbol after discovering this feature.

Comment: I am fairly good now at judging when it is about to happen and lift my finger off and re-apply it but I still get court out. Takes to long to do it character at a time! LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SwipeSelection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h2yrBK7MAY)

While this does not 'fix' your backspace you can use the 'shift' key en swipe over the keyboard to select the text you want to delete. avoiding you to have to hold down the backspace

Check out the video in the link.

Works on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: (Not sure where last comment went!?)
This is an amazing jb hack and I will definitely be using it (if I can remember each time!) thanks!

As you said it's not quite a fix to the issue but I think it is a significantly adequate alternative so as I suspect I won't find a hack that disables the feature I will mark this as the answer.

If anyone knows of a way of disabling this "feature" do pipe up still! :)